# Is it possible to use Python while in Recovery Mode?

Tags: terminal, command-line, recovery, python, data-recovery

Is it possible to access a Python terminal while in Recovery Mode?

```
$ /Volumes/macOS/usr/bin/python 

python: posix_spawn: 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: 
No such file or directory


$ /Volumes/macOS/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python 

dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
  Referenced from: /Volumes/macOS/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```